# Jbuilder Node Names for Polymorphic Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

If I have a jbuilder template containing this code:

```
json.reportable do |reportable|                  
       json.(report.reportable, *report.reportable_type.constantize.column_names)
end
```

How can I name the node by the reportable.report.reportable_type attribute, instead of "reportable" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it is right there in the documentation

```
json.set! report.reportable_type.underscore  do |reportable|                  
       json.(report.reportable, *report.reportable_type.constantize.column_names)
end
```